# Shape Key Drivers Messed Up

Tags: animation, drivers, shape-keys, pose-mode

I saw this video: https://youtu.be/Nc6ewpdBzxo, and I am trying to replicate it.  See Time (14:30) to see him put together the drivers. The Drive Equations are Tan(var/2) and Tan(var/2)-1.

It uses a simple shape key drive system to make the mine craft arm bend correctly.  I was having trouble getting the drivers to work and I think I have figured out why.  My value for the input variable system is different than in the video.  In the video it is 0, but my value for the input variable is -1.571 (-90 deg).

How do I correct this?  I could really use you guy's help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  My armature and mesh were both facing in the negative axis direction, so what I did was rotate them so they were facing in the positive direction, and then I applied rotations and corrected the rolls of the bones so that the rolls were 0 deg.  Then I recreated the drivers and it all worked!